# Check the render method of `component`

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom

im trying to set up a react-router-dom higher order components following a guide. I have an issue saying..

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>   Check the render method of `component`.

Here is my code.

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import Navigation from './Navigation';
import LandingPage from './Landing';
import SignUpPage from './SignUp';
import SignInPage from './SignIn';
import PasswordForgetPage from './PasswordForget';
import HomePage from './Home';
import AccountPage from './Account';

import * as routes from '../constants/routes';

const App = () =>
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Navigation />

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path={routes.LANDING} component={() => <LandingPage />} />
      <Route exact path={routes.SIGN_UP} component={() => <SignUpPage />} />
      <Route exact path={routes.SIGN_IN} component={() => <SignInPage />} />
      <Route exact path={routes.PASSWORD_FORGET} component={() => <PasswordForgetPage />} />
      <Route exact path={routes.HOME} component={() => <HomePage />} />
      <Route exact path={routes.ACCOUNT} component={() => <AccountPage />} />
    </div>
  </Router>

export default App;
```

and my index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
unregister();
```

Thanks.

Comment: you figure this out?

Comment: DId you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're mixing up your react router `Route` prop values. To assign a component to a `Route` there's a few different ways. One is with `component`, another is with `render`.

```
<Route ... component={LandingPage} />

<Route ... render={() => <LandingPage />} />
```

You're using the `render` syntax but the `component` prop. Either change `component` to `render`, or change `() => <LandingPage />` to `LandingPage` (and the same for the other routes ofc).

Comment: I changed to the component syntax and now get Check the render method of `Route`. it also gives the same error with the render syntax